# How to solve a Key Error 19 problem with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I've been using pandas to deal with dataframes and while cleaning those datas, I met a problem on iteration...

for example (something i tried to locate the error):

```
N_index = df.shape[0]
j = 0
while j < N_index:
  print(j, df.diag_1[j][0],'squalala')
  j += 1
```

This display this :

```
0 2 squalala
1 2 squalala
2 6 squalala
3 8 squalala
4 1 squalala
5 4 squalala
6 4 squalala
7 4 squalala
8 3 squalala
9 4 squalala
10 2 squalala
11 1 squalala
12 4 squalala
13 4 squalala
14 5 squalala
15 9 squalala
16 4 squalala
17 6 squalala
18 4 squalala
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2890             try:
-> 2891                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2892             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 19
```

And for some reasons (idk which) after the 18th index, it can't work, so if you have any idea on how to fix it or just why does it do that, I'll be really gratefull to you.

PS. I'm using a while loop and not a for loop on the exmaple but i tried both since I saw on antoher Stack Overflow post that this solved their issues, well for me it didn't ^^

PSS. I am using a notebook

EDIT : here I'm doing a `df.diag_1[j][0]` because I want to access the first element of the string of the line j in the column diag_1 of my dataframe –

Comment: You are mixing up rows and columns. df.shape[0] returns the number of rows in your dataframe.  But, when you do this df[j][0], the j is referencing the columns in the dataframe.

Comment: It seems to me that he is trying to index the rows of a column named `diag_1`, or?

Comment: @BraulioBarahona That's the idea, i want to access the first element of the string of the line j in the column diag_1 of my dataframe

Comment: @Pukki check out the code snippet I put, the indexing should work

Answer (score 1):

KeyError: 19 means the program is trying to get the 19th element, but it does not exist.

Could you try to print df directly? I suspect the index for the 19th row is not 19. In order to reset index, you could do:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a problem somewhere else, the indexing should work, see:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"one":["1X","2Y","3Z"]})                                                                          
N_index = df.shape[0]                                                                                                
j=0                                                                                                                  

while j < N_index: 
 print(j, df.one[j][0]) 
 j += 1
```

To make sure the indexing works like expected simply reset the index before you try to look up the rows in your loop:

```
df.reset_index()
```

Here is an example, when you index is not the standard 0 to N-1 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"one":["1X","2Y","3Z"]})
df['new_index'] = range(2,5) 
df = df.set_index("new_index") 
print(df)

# reset the index to make your loop work
df=df.reset_index() 

N_index = df.shape[0]                                                                                                
j=0                                                                                                                  

while j < N_index: 
 print(j, df.one[j][0]) 
 j += 1
```

**Note** that generally speaking one does not need to loop through a pandas data frame like you do, use for example the apply method, for example:

```
out= df.one.apply(lambda x:x[1])
```

will give you the second element of the string in each row. Take at pandas documentation, for example: [10-minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html); or the multiple questions here that deal with indexing.

Comment: Thank you, i will see if the problem comes from somewhere else because i see that tour code works... I'm still investigating for my problem, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

My investigation kept going and simply when I did a `df.head(25)`, I could see the different index going like:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
> **18**
> **22**
> **23** 24 25 26 27

As you can see, the index from 19 to 21 are missing (probably from a `dropna()` done precedently. So the error came probably from here since those indexes, as some of you mentioned, did not exist.

So I could just access the existing index by :

```
for j in df.index:
  print(j, df.diag_1[j][0]):
```

That has solved the problem.

Comment: are you sure this re-indexing works? does it not return NaN to the indexes that were dropped?

Comment: @BraulioBarahona actually I did an edit of this post but it seem that it didn't save so I'll do it again